# Как сделать чтоб при пуше менялась переменная

Tags: java, android

Такой вот вопос, у нас несколько человек работет над проектом, и в классе глобальных переменных есть такая `boolean isDebugMode`

Так вот вопрос в том, что при работе с кодом эта переменная `true` , но когда в основную бранч делаем пуш то она там должна быть `false` , но часто возникает ситуация когда просто кто то забывает ее перед пушем поставить в `false`

Можно ли написать какой то скрипт который при пуше будет автоматически менять эту переменную на `false` ?

Или может можно как то именно эту переменную исключитить из отслеживания гитом?
Чтоб она на удаленом репозитории всегда хранилась в значении `false`

Константа `BuildConfig.DEBUG` не подходит, потому что есть тесты которые мы проводим на дебаг версии

Comment: Может вам подойдёт константа `BuildConfig.DEBUG`? В релиз билдах она false в дебаг true.

Comment: @eugeneek добавил в вопрос. Не совсем подходит это решение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вынесите свою переменную в `buildTypes`:

```
buildTypes {

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix "-debug"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_DEBUG_MODE", "true"
        }

        debugWithFalseDebugMode {
            initWith debug
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_DEBUG_MODE", "false"
        }

        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_DEBUG_MODE", "false"
        }
    }
```

Затем, в файле глобальных констант, берите ее значение:

```
public class Config {

    public static final Boolean IS_DEBUG_MODE = BuildConfig.IS_DEBUG_MODE ;

    ...

}
```

Теперь используйте соответствующий `buildType`, когда это нужно.

Как вариант, можно динамически менять эту переменную в `gradle`:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_DEBUG_MODE", isDebugMode()
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_DEBUG_MODE", isDebugMode()
    }
}

def isDebugMode() {
    def value = project.getProperties().get("IS_DEBUG_MODE")
    return value != null ? value : "true"
}
```

Используете так:

```
./gradlew iDebug -PisDebugMode=true
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Хранить в файле конфигов. При старте считывать это значение в переменную.
2. Залить в гит.
3. Добавить в гит игнор.